# Problema al imprimir elementos de una lista enlazada en C

Tags: c, nodos

Para practicar listas enlazadas, estoy haciendo un registro de pacientes de un hospital en c que permita agregar pacientes al registro, darlos de alta e imprimir todos los datos de los distintos pacientes (imprimir todos los elementos de la lista). El problema es que pareciera que al agregar un nodos se sobrescriben, por lo tanto al imprimir todos los elementos, muestra el mismo nodo repetidamente.

También sucede que cuando quiero imprimir los elementos de un nodo en especifico (`switch case`(3)) solo funciona cuando quiero imprimir los elementos del ultimo nodo agregado.

**Este es el codigo ya modificado pasando un puntero a puntero a nodo**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

typedef struct nodo{
    char *nombre, *enfermedad, *edad, *peso, *altura;
    struct nodo *next;
}NODO;



NODO* nodoalfinal(NODO** inicio, char *nombre, char *enfermedad, char *edad, char *peso, char *altura);

NODO* borrarnodo(NODO* inicio, char *nombre);

void imprimirlista(NODO* inicio);

int main() {
    NODO *inicio=NULL;
    int res;
    char enfermedadaux[20], nombreaux[20], paciente[20], pesoaux[10], alturaaux[10], edadaux[10];
    printf("Ingrese pacientes a la base de datos\n");
    while(res!=0){
        printf("Ingrese el nombre del paciente:");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(nombreaux);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\nIngrese la condicion que padece el paciente:");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(enfermedadaux);
        printf("\nIngrese la edad del paciente:");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(edadaux);
        printf("\nIngrese el peso del paciente:");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(pesoaux);
        printf("\nIngrese la estatura del paciente ej(1.8m) :");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(alturaaux);
        inicio=nodoalfinal(&inicio, nombreaux, enfermedadaux, edadaux, pesoaux, alturaaux);
        printf("\nTabule 1 para ingresar otro paciente, 0 para avanzar:");
        scanf("%d",&res);
    }
    printf("\nIngrese 1 para dar de alta un paciente\nIngrese 2 para agregar un paciente al registro\nIngrese 3 para obtener los datos de un paciente\nIngrese 4 para mostrar los registros de todos los pacientes\nIngrese 5 para salir\n");
    scanf("%d",&res);
    switch(res){
        case(1):{
            printf("Ingrese el nombre del paciente:");
            fflush(stdin);
            gets(paciente);
            fflush(stdin);
            inicio=borrarnodo(inicio,paciente);
            printf("\n------PACIENTE DADO DE ALTA------");
            }break;
        case(2):{
            printf("Ingrese el nombre del paciente:");
            fflush(stdin);
            gets(nombreaux);
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("\nIngrese la condicion que padece el paciente:");
            fflush(stdin);
            gets(enfermedadaux);
            printf("\nIngrese la edad del paciente:");
            fflush(stdin);
            gets(edadaux);
            printf("\nIngrese el peso del paciente:");
            fflush(stdin);
            gets(pesoaux);
            printf("\nIngrese la estatura del paciente ej(1.8m) :");
            fflush(stdin);
            gets(alturaaux);
            inicio=nodoalfinal(&inicio, nombreaux, enfermedadaux, edadaux, pesoaux, alturaaux);
            printf("\n------PACIENTE INGRESADO------");
        }break;
        case(3):{
            printf("Ingrese el nombre del paciente:");
            fflush(stdin);
            gets(paciente);
            fflush(stdin);
            while((inicio!=NULL)and(strcmp(inicio->nombre,paciente)!=0)){
                inicio=inicio->next;
            }
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("Nombre:%s Diagnostico:%s Edad:%s Peso:%s Altura:%s\t",inicio->nombre, inicio->enfermedad, inicio->edad, inicio->peso, inicio->altura);
        }break;
        case(4):{
            imprimirlista(inicio);
        }break;
        case(5):{
        }break;
    }
    return 0;
}

    NODO* nodoalfinal(NODO** inicio, char *nombre, char *enfermedad, char *edad, char *peso, char *altura){
        NODO *nuevo = new NODO;
        nuevo->nombre=nombre;
        nuevo->enfermedad=enfermedad;
        nuevo->edad=edad;
        nuevo->altura=altura;
        nuevo->peso=peso;
        nuevo->next=NULL;
        
        if (inicio == NULL){
            *inicio = nuevo;
        }
        else{
            NODO *aux = *inicio;
            while (aux->next != NULL)
                aux = aux->next;
            aux->next=nuevo;
        }
        return *inicio;
    }
        
    NODO* borrarnodo(NODO* inicio, char *nombre){
            NODO *aux, *anterior;
            aux=inicio;
            if((inicio!=NULL)and(strcmp(inicio->nombre,nombre)!=0)){
                aux=inicio;
                inicio=inicio->next;
                free(aux);
            }
            else{
                while((aux!=NULL)and(strcmp(aux->nombre,nombre)!=0)){
                    anterior=aux;
                    aux=aux->next;
                }
                if(aux!=NULL){
                    anterior->next=aux->next;
                    free(aux);
                }
            }
            return inicio;
        }
            
    void imprimirlista(NODO* inicio){
        NODO *actual= new NODO;
        actual=inicio;
        while(actual!=NULL){
            printf("%s %s %s %s %s\n", actual->nombre, actual->enfermedad, actual->edad, actual->peso, actual->altura);
            actual=actual->next;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

En la información en el `NODO` has puesto los campos como punteros a buffers. Esos punteros los asignas en la función `nodoalfinal` utilizando los parámetros que le pasas a la función, que son direcciones de los buffers en los que has almacenado los datos entrados por el usuario.

Para entrar los datos declaras esos buffers utilizando `char enfermedadaux[20], nombreaux[20], paciente[20], pesoaux[10], alturaaux[10], edadaux[10];`, lo cual no está mal, y esos son los que pasas a la función `nodoalfinal`.

Los datos se sobreescriben porque en la función `nodoalfinal` no realizas una copia de los datos hacia unos buffers nuevos sino que todos los nodos creados van a apuntar a los mismos buffers.

En la función `nodoalfinal`, en lugar de asignar directamente los campos del nodo `nuevo`, debes crear copias dinámicas de cada uno de los buffers que recibes antes de asignarlos al nodo.

También tendrás que adaptar la función `borrarnodo` para que libere esos buffers dinámicos.

No te pongo el código completo para que puedas continuar practicando, pero si tienes alguna dificultad más puedes editar tu pregunta para ampliarla y te intentaremos ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

> estoy haciendo un registro de pacientes de un hospital en c

Empiezas mal, tu código es incompatible con [c](/questions/tagged/c):

- La cabecera `<iostream>` es de C++.
- C no dispone de espacios de nombres.

Un compilador de C fallará al intentar compilar tu programa; en realidad has programado en C++ con la mayoría de código como C.

---

> El problema es que pareciera que al agregar un nodos se sobrescriben

Lo que está sucediendo es que nunca enlazas los nodos, por lo tanto nunca creas una lista enlazada:

```
if (inicio == NULL){
    inicio=nuevo;
}
else{
    NODO *aux = inicio;
    while (aux->next != NULL)
        aux = aux->next;
    aux->next=nuevo;
}
```

Vamos a verlo paso a paso con un poco de ASCII art.

1. En la primera llamada, inicio es `NULL`, por lo tanto entramos en la primera rama del `if`:

   ```
   [inicio] --> NULL
   ```

   Y queda de la siguiente manera:

   ```
                __________
   [inicio] --> | nombre | --> "Primero\0"
                | next   | --> NULL
                ⎻⎻⎻⎻⎻⎻⎻⎻⎻⎻⎻
   ```
2. Suponiendo que todo vaya bien (que no es el caso, ya lo veremos luego) `inicio` conserva el nodo de la llamada anterior y en la segunda llamada empezamos igualando `aux` a `inicio`:

   ```
                   __________
   [inicio] ---+-> | nombre | --> "Primero\0"
   [ aux  ] --/    | next   | --> NULL
                   ⎻⎻⎻⎻⎻⎻⎻⎻⎻⎻⎻
   ```

   Dado que `aux->next` es `NULL` no entraremos en el bucle, hacemos que `aux->next` sea el nuevo nodo:

   ```
                   __________
   [inicio] ---+-> | nombre | --> "Primero\0"
   [ aux  ] --/    | next   | --> __________
                   ⎻⎻⎻⎻⎻⎻⎻⎻⎻⎻⎻     | nombre | --> "Segundo\0"
                                  | next   | --> NULL
                                  ⎻⎻⎻⎻⎻⎻⎻⎻⎻⎻⎻
   ```

A priori parece que todo va bien pero sabemos que no es cierto ¿Qué está pasando en realidad? La realidad es que nunca cambias `inicio`. Todas tus funciones reciben el puntero a nodo por copia y modificas la copia dejando el original intacto, puedes [verlo con este ejemplo](https://tio.run/##vZLLjsIgFIbX5SlOnIypxjFjZullpU/gtolBQIcED4SCC43P3jm0Tq3GnYk7@M/tOz@Ir70QVfWhUZgoFczKILUd/y4Y0xhAanWCOUy@p/U1eFXS9WfK2NFqCc7iJuImZeUpPnQRg/J2wM4sc56kXZ71irAycI0ANfh0BfZYlgLrCEdurH@QKb@ReSrjsimTBVLGiFL6124jaA/taGLL/ofNoZ/YaulGs1Sli9RQKgOCH7badge/EfTSmHzgGvPkZ21b18e0QPL8boEV1hWgnrM@JX3Z0M5D3@mPULL1FgyHXUShLd4g3gbsVYgegf7tpar@AA):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int diez = 10;
int tres = 3;

void pon_un_diez(int *puntero)
{
    printf( "\tEl puntero es %p\n"
        "\tSu valor es %p\n"
        "\tEl valor apuntado es %d\n\n",
        &puntero, puntero, *puntero);

    puntero = &diez;

    printf( "\tDespues del cambio\n"
        "\tEl puntero es %p\n"
        "\tSu valor es %p\n"
        "\tEl valor apuntado es %d\n\n",
        &puntero, puntero, *puntero);
}

int main(void)
{
    int *puntero = &tres;

    printf( "En main el puntero es %p\n"
        "Su valor es %p\n"
        "El valor apuntado es %d\n\n",
        &puntero, puntero, *puntero);

    pon_un_diez(puntero);

    printf( "En main despues de la funcion\n"
        "El puntero es %p\n"
        "Su valor es %p\n"
        "El valor apuntado es %d\n\n",
        &puntero, puntero, *puntero);

    return 0;
}
```

Que genera la siguiente salida (los valores de los punteros cambian en cada ejecución, estos valores son orientativos):

> ```
> En main el puntero es 0xaaaaaaaaaaaa
> Su valor es 0xbbbbbb
> El valor apuntado es 3
>
>         El puntero es 0xcccccccccccc
>         Su valor es 0xbbbbbb
>         El valor apuntado es 3
>
>         Despues del cambio
>         El puntero es 0xcccccccccccc
>         Su valor es 0xdddddd
>         El valor apuntado es 10
>
> En main despues de la funcion
> El puntero es 0xaaaaaaaaaaaa
> Su valor es 0xbbbbbb
> El valor apuntado es 3
> ```

Si quieres solucionar el problema, deberás pasar un puntero a puntero a nodo si realmente pretendes programar en C, si tu idea es programar en C++ puedes usar una referencia a puntero.

###### `C`

```
NODO* nodoalfinal(NODO** inicio, char *nombre, ...);
//                    ^^ <-- Puntero a puntero a nodo
...
inicio=nodoalfinal(&inicio, nombreaux, ...);
//                 ^ <-- Dirección del nodo inicial
...
if (inicio == NULL){
    *inicio=nuevo;
//  ^ <-- Modificar el valor apuntado
}
```

###### `C++`

```
NODO* nodoalfinal(NODO*& inicio, char *nombre, ...);
//                    ^^ <-- Referencia a puntero a nodo, no es necesario otro cambio
```

Comment: Hola, antes que nada gracias por la ayuda, probé modificando el código de las dos maneras, cuando paso un puntero a puntero a nodo el programa no compila correctamente, por lo que probé utilizando la referencia a puntero a nodo, en este caso el programa compila sin problemas pero sigue sin funcionar correctamente, ya no se que mas probar.

Comment: @MartinBottino piensa que la versión puntero a puntero requiere cambiar el tipo del parámetro `inicio`, cambios dentro de la función y cambios en la llamada a la función. Si no haces todos esos cambios la versión puntero a puntero te fallará.

Comment: Para la version puntero a puntero realice todos los cambios que mencionaste en la primer respuesta, en la llamada a la funcion tambien agregue `&inicio` , luego en el codigo de la funcion tambien agregue * a inicio en la parte del else porque sino me daba error.  `  else{
   NODO *aux = *inicio;
   while (aux->next != NULL)
    aux = aux->next;
   aux->next=nuevo;
  }
  return *inicio;  `  Aun asi el programa sigue fallando, podrias darme una mano por favor?

Comment: @MartinBottino Sin ver el código no puedo adivinar qué estás haciendo mal: si tienes problemas sobre la misma pregunta, edita la pregunta poniendo los nuevos detalles. Si tienes un nuevo problema, haz una pregunta nueva.

Comment: Ya edite la pregunta, el codigo es el mismo pero con las modificaciones que sugeriste, no se si me falte algo mas.

Comment: @MartinBottino ¿El comportamiento sigue siendo el mismo?

Comment: No, ahora luego de ingresar los primeros datos el programa se cierra.